# Is it possible to have starting code executed in a WCF Service before someone connects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Is there a way to have initialization code that runs when the Website with the Web Service is started or the App Pool is recycled? The code should run before someone attempts to connect to the Service. I thought `Application_Start` in global.asax should work, but this one is also only called as soon as the first client connects. Or at least something like a 'CronJob' that runs every time the App Pool is recycled and calls the Web Service once.

**Update**: It should be executed immediately at startup (start of IIS site or recycle of App Pool). Because I have some time intensive static initialization code, the first client that connects has a long waiting time before the call returns. I would like to prevent that because it happens every time the App Pool for this Service is recycled.

Comment: Should it be executed immediately at startup, or any time before first usage? In other words, would it be valid to prepend that action to the *first* user interaction, rather than automatically calling it?

Comment: It should be executed immediately at startup. Because I have some time intensive static initialization code, the first client that connects has a long waiting time. I would like to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 and up supports [application pool warm-up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668225%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The IIS application pool warmup feature. This feature is activated by
>   an HTTP request and is intended for use in most ASP.NET applications.
>   To perform application warmup, IIS launches a worker process and then
>   preloads the CLR and any required assemblies. Next, it uses an HTTP
>   request simulator to mimic a real request, which triggers remaining
>   start-up tasks such as compiling and caching pages, and creating
>   database connections. To use this approach, write custom start-up code
>   in the Application_Start method in Global.asax. Then configure IIS
>   application warmup (in the applicationHost.config file) for the URL of
>   the application. For information about how to configure IIS for
>   application warmup, see Configuration Paths .

.Net 4.0 and up supports ASP.Net preload manager:

> In .NET Framework 4, ASP.NET supports a custom application preload
>   feature. This feature can be activated by either an HTTP or non-HTTP
>   request, and it gives you programmatic control over all preload tasks.
>   This approach is intended for relatively complex server application
>   scenarios where the application needs a protocol-independent mechanism
>   in order to carry out custom preload tasks. An example of such an
>   application is Windows Communication Foundation (WCF). To use the
>   ASP.NET application preload manager, you write a managed type that
>   contains your preload code. The type must  implement the
>   [`IProcessHostPreloadClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.iprocesshostpreloadclient.aspx) interface. You then configure your custom
>   type as a preload provider type in IIS configuration in the
>   applicationHost.config file.

Answer (score 1):

`Application_Start` is the right place to add the code, but you have to change the settings of the application pool. Normally IIS only starts the application pool and web site when the first request is made. That can be changed with the `AlwaysRunning` option in IIS 7.5.

In `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config:`

```
<applicationPools> 
  <add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" /> 
</applicationPools>
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260(v=azure.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I just cannot get it to work. I tried everything from the link. Also these two Parameters `serviceAutoStartProvider=”Service” serviceAutoStartMode=”All/Custom”` require the AppFabric as it seems. Does it work without it?